# nodejs force synchronous call to store json

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function which makes

1. n GET calls to a server (in a for loop),
2. gets the json responses
3. assembles the responses together to create one json
4. and stores that json in MongoDB

   I want to wait for all the responses to finish, consolidates the responses and then stores that resulting one json. Below is the code

   function getBucketStoreJson(servers,username,password){

   ```
   var tmp_json = {};
   for (var j = 0; j < servers.length; j++){
       var server = servers[j];
       var options = {
         'host':  server.toString(),
         'port': port,
         'path': somepath,
         'method': 'GET',
         'auth':username.toString()+':'+password.toString()            
       };
   //logger.debug("options : " + JSON.stringify(options));
     var request = http.request(options,function(res){
       var fullBucketJson = "";            
       logger.info('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
       logger.info('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
       res.setEncoding('utf8');
       res.on('data',function(chunk){
           fullBucketJson += chunk;
       });
       res.on('end',function(){
          <more code that assembles the jsons together>
       });
   });     
   //res.end();    
   request.on('error',(e) => {

    });
    request.end();
   }}
   ```

I have to wait for above function to finish before I can store the resulting json. When I pass the store function as a callback, nothing is saved because of the asynchronous nature of the GET calls.

How do I force the function to complete and then save the resulting JSON ?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your probelm can be easily solved using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Read the documentation as to how this works, but basically you will add each promise to an array, making an array of promises, when you invoke `Promise.all()` on this array, it will wait for all of the async calls to complete.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using bluebird promises, since it is much easier. But promises was the correct, easy approach. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.